# Code First: Is there a command to show what database I am pointing to?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, code-first

When doing a `database-update` in the package manager console, you can add `-verbose` and it will tell you, among other things, what database (server, database name, etc) it is executing the update against.

While that's handy, I'd like to know ahead of time what database I'm going to update. I've looked for, but can't find a command that just tells me what database I'm pointing to.

Does such a command exist?

(I mean, I know I can just look in the config files. So, I guess I'm just being lazy.  But when I have an update all ready to go and I'm in the console, it's a bit annoying to have to go hunt down the proper config file(s) and make sure I'm on the right DB.)

Comment: i know it's not what you're looking for, but have you tried writing to file with verbose (data-update -script -verbose) ? 
Maybe that way you can see the info without commiting to the database.

Comment: It will use the database for the web.config that you have set as the startup project and will run the migrations of the target project that you have selected in the package manager console.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira - good idea.  Not, as you said, what I was looking for, but a good work-around.

Comment: @Luke, yes of course.  I know that :).  I was just hoping to not have to go check the config file manually.

Answer (score 0):

It will use the database for the web.config that you have set as the startup project and will run the migrations of the target project that you have selected in the package manager console.  And as you probably already know, it uses the connection string name that has been specified in the constructor for the DbContext associated with your code-first migrations.

My suggestion, if you are paranoid, would be to use the `update-database` [parameters](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/) to ensure that it is using the configuration that you expect, rather than relying on them to be automatically inferred.

> **-StartUpProjectName string**
>
> Specifies the configuration file to use for named connection strings. If omitted, the specified project’s
> configuration file is used.
>
> **-ProjectName**
>
> Specifies the configuration file to use for named connection strings.
> If omitted, the specified project’s configuration file is used.
>
> **-ConnectionStringName**
>
> Specifies the name of a connection string to use from the application’s >configuration file.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  All good to know.  I guess I was hoping for some command like `target-database` and have it spit out: `Target database is: 'NameOfCatalog' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).`  like it does with `-verbose`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston - Sounds like a good suggestion for the team, or implement it yourself and submit a pull request, since it's open source.  See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework